# How to read json file online client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, json, client-side

I have a JSON file on my website, and I want to access it from client-side vanilla javascript. How do I do that?

I don't want any HTML involved, like linking to the JSON file in the HTML and then accessing it via JavaScript. I need it to be in JavaScript and JSON, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace URL with your JSON URL.You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to send request and receive response as a promise.

```js
// Replace URL with your url
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**Using Async-await**

```js
async function getData(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error handling here
    console.log(error);
  }
}

// Replace url with your url
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

getData(url);
```